# Multiprocessing emcee not working in Spyder (Python 3.9.7)

Tags: anaconda, multiprocessing, spyder, emcee

I'm new to this so please forgive me if I forget to add enough information. I have an MCMC code that uses emcee and that works perfectly fine in my "normal" terminal, with the Python 3.5.2 version. Recently, I started using Spyder within Anaconda and the code does not work, in particular I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in 
_bootstrap
self.run()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
task = get()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'lnprob' on <module '__main__' (built-in)
```

"lnprob" is the function where I calculate the posterior distribution. I assume the error has to do with the multiprocessing, but don't know how to solve it. The python version I have in the environment is Python 3.9.7.

Many thanks

Comment: This error can happen in a few scenarios. Most commonly it is when using an interactive prompt rather than executing an entire file (common with jupyter).. what is your OS and spyder version? How do you execute the file (run file with F5? debug file? run segment with F9? etc..)

Comment: This can also happen specifically with MacOS when moving to a newer version of python. In version 3.6, the default "start method" was changed, which makes some previously working code break (particularly locally bound functions)